# How to count no of rows and column in csv file using c programming

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, data-structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    FILE *fileptr;
    int count_lines = 0;
    char filechar[40], chr;
 
    printf("Enter file name: ");
    scanf("%s", filechar);
    fileptr = fopen(filechar, "r");
    chr = getc(fileptr);
    while (chr != EOF)
    {
        if (chr == 'n')
        {
            count_lines = count_lines + 1;
        }
            chr = getc(fileptr);
    }
    fclose(fileptr); //close file.
    printf("There are %d lines in %s  in a file\n", count_lines, filechar);
    return 0;
}
```

here i am able to count the no of row but i dont know how to count the no of col please help me out
the  main is i not am able to count no of comma in csv file so if i am able to count no of comma then it easy to know how much column in csv file

Comment: Use `fgets` and `strstr`. And punctuation. Thanks.

Comment: `int chr;` not char

Comment: `if ((count_lines == 0) && (chr == ',')) commas = commas + 1; /* count commas in 1st line */`

Comment: @pmg now i do the respective changes but it show error that nonportable pointer convertor

Comment: @PrasadTupe The error message certainly contains the number of the line where the error was detected. Please paste the relevant error  message as is.  Please update the code in the question if you made any changes to it and are referring to  this modified  code   in your comments.